# Why First Commit (Root Commit) has time stamp greater than Second Commit?

Tags: git, unix-timestamp, git-log

In my project (tracked with git), The root commit has time stamp greater than second commit. How and Why it is so?

Time stamp for first 7 commits using

> git log --pretty=format:"%at"

```
1515067338
1515051752
1515050695
1514976857
1514844972
1514789595
1514828353
```

Comment: It's not possible to say without more information. How did you make these commits? Can you provide a [mcve] so  that others can reproduce this behavior?

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow, don't know how to properly format the questions. Can anyone help?

Comment: A commit is created on a client's machine, then uploaded to the server. It is possible that the client's clock was incorrect when they made the commit. From a logical point of view, the child commit can not exist before the parent, so the timestamp must be incorrect.

Comment: @MattClark That can be a possibility that client machine clock was not correct at time of commit, but git must provide some error on this incorrect possiblity(logic). Isn't it ?

Comment: Moreover @MattClark thanks for editing my question. Can you please give me a link for a guide on 'How to properly format your questions in stackoverflow?'

Comment: @jaspu You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for question/answer formatting.

Comment: I think Matt was asking for more information, rather than better formatting. Like who created the commits?, what does the rest of the commit meta data say? Etc

Answer (score 1):

> The root commit has time stamp greater than second commit. How and Why it is so?

Because the person why made the root commit set the commit date to a time later than the person who made the second commit set the commit date.

```
git init test

cd test

git commit --allow-empty --date=2038-12-31T23:59:59 -m 'Root commit'
git commit --allow-empty --date=1970-01-01T00:00:00 -m 'Second commit'

git log --pretty=format:"%at"
# 18446744073709548016
# 2177449199
```